# {Solved} Menu items spread out when expanding the menu. WPF Application

Tags: xml, wpf, menu

EDIT:
I figured it out after 1 hour of trials and errors:

```
<Button Click="ToggleMenuButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="StrzalkaImage" Source="/MenuSandwich_img_MainAppMenuLeft.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="MenuLabel" Text="Menu" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
```

#### ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW

I am encountering an issue with the menu items in my WPF application, which is positioned on the left side of the screen.

I've designed the menu to expand or collapse upon clicking the "Menu Sandwich" icon. However, when expanding the menu, the images within it seem to shift inconsistently away from the left side of the screen by varying amounts of pixels. Furthermore, upon collapsing the menu, they fail to return to their designated positions.

I've attempted to troubleshoot the problem by experimenting with properties such as `HorizontalAlignment="Left" or "Stretch"`, as well as trying out a `DockPanel` instead of a `StackPanel` and adjusting the architecture, but none of these solutions have resolved the issue.

Below you can find the sample code (all menu items follow the same pattern):

```
<Grid x:Name="MainAppLeftMenu" Background="green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50">
                <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->

                <!-- Lewa strona ekranu -->
                <StackPanel Height="auto"  Orientation="Vertical">
                    <!-- Przycisk rozszerzający/zamykający menu -->
                    <Button Click="ToggleMenuButton_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Image x:Name="StrzalkaImage" Source="/MenuSandwich_img_MainAppMenuLeft.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MenuLabel" Text="Menu" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="25,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
    </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

[image: Menu Comparison]

Comment: It's good that you've solved your problem, and it's great that you've followed-up for the benefit of future readers.  The best way to present your follow-up is by actually adding it as an *answer* rather than an  edit to your question.   You can still do that by [edit]ing your question and moving the answer portion to an actual answer here.  You can removed `{Solved}` from the title and ***accept*** your (self-)answer instead. 
Thank you.